# Aging - Calendar and Business Days Different Records of Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, calendar, case, date-difference

I am currently using SQL Server 2012 and I have an aging question. I tried to include some sample data below with 4 records.

```
FileNumber    FileType     CompletedDate
 90440        Internal      8/11/2017
 90440        Strategy       NULL
 90441        Internal      8/10/2017
 90441        Strategy       NULL
```

A Strategies' aging is calculated from the Internal FileType's Completed Date all the way up to the Strategy FileType's Completed Date. Every FileNumber can have multiple FileTypes associated with it. If the Strategy's Completed Date is NULL, then it would be from Internal FileType's Completed Date all the way up to today's date or GETDATE().

So I'm trying to show Count of Pending Strategies and their current aging in Business and Calendar Days...so essentially I would want the data to return like this.

```
File Number    FileType    AgeBusiness  AgeCalendar
 90440          Strategy     2            4
 90441          Strategy     3            5
```

Any clue on how I would go about this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You say "If the Strategy's Completed Date is NULL, then...", what about if it's not NULL?

Comment: Can you explain "Every FileNumber can have multiple FileTypes associated with it."? Are you saying there can be more than one "Internal" and "Strategy"? Also, business days can be tricky with holidays.  Do you have a "days" table?

Comment: @justice - In terms of this example...FileNumber can have 1 Internal File and 1 Strategy File associated with it. No multiples. And I do have a DT.DIM days table.

Comment: - Element..I got that part already. Im strictly focused on when it's NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may work but I'm not 100% sure since it depends on what sort of Filetypes are in the table, whether you are accounting for holidays, what happens when Strategy (or whatever is the latest file type) *has* a value for completed date.

```
;WITH Internal AS
(
    select  FileNumber, FileType,
            DATEDIFF(day,CompletedDate,getdate())- (datediff(wk, CompletedDate, getdate()) * 2) -
                case when datepart(dw, CompletedDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
                case when datepart(dw, getdate()) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as AgeBusiness,
            DATEDIFF(day,CompletedDate,getdate()) as AgeCalendar
    from @test
    where FileType = 'Internal'
)
select t.FileNumber, t.FileType, i.AgeBusiness, i.AgeCalendar
from @test t
inner join Internal i on
    (t.FileNumber = i.FileNumber)
where CompletedDate is null
```

the problem with the above is it wouldn't show a row if Strategy (or whatever is the latest file type) HAS a completed date.  Therefore you may want something like

```
;WITH Internal AS
(
    select  FileNumber, FileType,
            DATEDIFF(day,CompletedDate,getdate())- (datediff(wk, CompletedDate, getdate()) * 2) -
                case when datepart(dw, CompletedDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
                case when datepart(dw, getdate()) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as AgeBusiness,
            DATEDIFF(day,CompletedDate,getdate()) as AgeCalendar
    from @test
    where FileType = 'Internal'
), Latest AS
(
    select FileNumber, FileType, RANK() OVER   
        (PARTITION BY FileNumber ORDER BY COALESCE(CompletedDate,GETDATE()) DESC) AS rnk
    from @test
)
select l.FileNumber, l.FileType, i.AgeBusiness, i.AgeCalendar
from Latest l
inner join Internal i on
    (l.FileNumber = i.FileNumber)
where rnk = 1
```

where it would show the row regardless of if it's null or not, but at the expense of adding a RANK() which is more intensive.

Comment: Difference between my query and @justiceorjustus is I assume that if you had multiple FileTypes, the latest one would be the one without a CompletedDate as that Filetype is the one you want to show.  It has the problem of what to do if there is a value for CompletedDate though (hence why I asked).  If you only want to show the Strategy FileType then his would be a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a CTE but I included it to make it more readable.

```
WITH DateRanges AS (
SELECT yt.FileNumber
    ,yt.FileType
    ,SELECT TOP 1 CompletedDate FROM YourTable WHERE yt.FileNumber = FileNumber AND FileType = 'Internal'  AS InternalCompletedDate
    ,CASE WHEN yt.CompletedDate IS NULL THEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) ELSE yt.CompletedDate END AS StrategyCompletedDate -- I forgot the NULL part too...
FROM YourTable yt
WHERE yt.FileType = 'Strategy'
)

SELECT FileNumber
    ,FileType
    ,(DATEDIFF(dd,InternalCompletedDate, StrategyCompletedDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, InternalCompletedDate, StrategyCompletedDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, InternalCompletedDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, StrategyCompletedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AgeBusiness    
    ,DATEDIFF(dd, InternalCompletedDate, StrategyCompletedDate) AS AgeCalendar
    FROM DateRanges
```

Edit: Should be good now. I rushed it a bit.